# About curent on the diode

Tags: current, diodes

What is the internal structure difference between diode can take current and another one can take more current than the first one?

Answer (score 5):

The higher-current diode has a larger junction *area*. It also has heavier leads that help conduct heat away from the junction.

Comment: Size does make a difference. As in other areas.